# Loading screen coverd by the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I made a loading screen on my personal website. While I was testing, I found that the navigation bar will cover my loading screen when I go into the website.

I want my loading screen can cover the entire screen when I go into the website. How can I do that?

This is my code, css and js.

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/loading.js"></script>
<div class="load_screen">
 <img class="load_screen" src="/assets/img/logo_loading.png">
</div>
    
<!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
<div class="w3-top">
 <div class="w3-bar w3-xlarge w3-black w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off baloo">
  <a href="https://www.test.com/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
  <a href="/test" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">test</a>
  <a href="/test" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">test</a>
  <a href="/test" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">test</a>
 </div>
</div>
    
<!-- Navbar on small screens -->
<div class="w3-bar-block w3-white w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium baloo">
 <a href="https://www.test.com/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">Home</a>
 <a href="/test" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">test</a>
 <a href="/test" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">test</a>
 <a href="/test" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">test/a>
</div>

div.load_screen {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  }
    
img.load_screen {
  z-index: 9999999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -27px 0 0 -95px; /* -image-height/2 0 0 -image-width/2 */
  background: white;
  }
```

[This is the screen that when I go into the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkwWC.png)

Comment: Just move the z-index to div.load_screen class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the **z-index** to **div.load_screen**.

```
div.load_screen {
  z-index: 9999999;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}
```

**z-index** is relative to its container so your image only sits above everything within the **div.load_screen** element.

As the nav bar comes later in the HTML, it will be positioned above the load screen as neither has a z-index set.